# Deallocation triggers munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I'm testing some software in MPI environment (RedHat Centros). I'm using Totalview to debug the scripts but I've come across an error in a well established library that I cannot seem to find even with the debugger.
The error:

```
*** glibc detected *** master.exe: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer:
0x000000001584c510 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x75f3e)[0x2b27fb025f3e]
```

The culprit script comes from a deallocation in the subroutine cleanup(). The script is a pretty long so will the put the relevant lines and variables associated with the error. I found the line that triggers the crash only by stepping through with Totalview. Even though I have compiled with "traceback" it generates a trace not to the line in the code but rather to the libc.so and grib_api.so with lots of hexadecimal information :-( 
I also did some research into this type of problem and many suggest looking for an out of bound error. I've compiled with this flag and checked the size of nch, which never exceeds 5. So I'm sure it is not writing out of bounds. I'm using Intel Compiler version 15.0.1.133. Any idea what I can do to find the cause of this problem?

Appreciate your thoughts on this.

```
subroutine getem(...)

implicit none

INTEGER :: cha(5)
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: id(:)
INTEGER :: nch

nch = 5
ALLOCATE(id(5),stat=err)
if(err .ne. 0) exit
id(1:nch) = cha(1:nch)) + 1

call cleanup()

contains

subroutine cleanup()

IF (ALLOCATED(id)) DEALLOCATE(id)
end subroutine cleanup

end subroutine getem
```

Comment: This can be caused by almost anything. Most likely an out-of bounds access in your arrays **anywhere** in the code. You should run your code with as many error checking options as you can enable for your compiler. You can also try Valgrind.

Comment: You say you are sure you are not out of bounds. Did you compile the **entire** code with the check flag? The error can be anywhere. Try producing a [mcve] by disabling various parts of the code and still crashing.

Comment: As Vladimir says it could be anything. Another possibility - you do have an interface in scope at the calling point for getem?

Comment: Yes, I have an interface and the arguments are good. I understand now the scope of this error. So I looked at the new code I edited and found an array with slice indices arr(1:0) = 1+x. This was probably the cause. I'm testing it now. Thanks you all for your advice :-)